# Odoo13: How to 'Group By' in the 'Export Data' screen when exporting to xlsx

Tags: odoo-13

Run Odoo13 CE locally, go to any list view, Contacts for example. Select some records and select "Export" from Actions menu, then export to xlsx, this works fine.
Now I need to do "Group By", for this I traced the code to know how export works, and I found in the file

```
addons/web/controllers/main.py
```

a method 'base' that is being called in every export

```
def base(self, data, token):
    params = json.loads(data)
...
   
    groupby = params.get('groupby')
    if not import_compat and groupby:
        groupby_type = [Model._fields[x.split(':')[0]].type for x in groupby]
...
```

I need to send a "Group By" field to this method among the other parameters, but I can not find a clue how to do that, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Just make a "Group By" one or more than one fields in the list view, select the records you need to export and then click the `"Export"` menu item from the `actions` menu. You will see the result xlsx file grouped by the fields you selected